# Adapter Design Pattern with one Adaptee class inheriting the other?

Tags: design-patterns, adapter, class-design, ooad

I've recently came across this question and I'm just curious if my answer is correct, and if not, where I made a mistake.

**My Task:**

The signatures of classes A and B are incompatible. Class C is to connect A and B with the Design Pattern Adapter.

What are the advantages of having C inherit from A and B? Explain whether it would make sense to have B inherit from A and C inherit from B.

**My answer:**

The advantage of making C inherit from A and B is that the signature conflict can be resolved, while A and B could still be instantiated separately.

It would not make sense to have B inherit from A and C inherit from B, because if the functionality that previously caused the conflict is inherited from A to C, B has to take over the implementation of A, the functionality of B would be changed, this would not be the purpose of the design pattern adapter.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Which class should be adapted to the other one? If you want an instance of A be working as a an instance of B, then C should extend B, wrap the instance of A, implement the interface desired for B, and call appropriate methods of the instance of A.

Comment: I don't think the task is about whether A should be adapted to B or vice versa (you can assume for example that B should be adapted to A), but rather about the advantages if C inherits from A and B and weather it would make sense to have B inherit from A and C inherit from B.

Comment: What do you mean by, "_A and B could still be instantiated separately_"? The rest of your answer looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Adapter Pattern** (like all other GoF design patterns) has a well documented structure. There are two ways to implement this pattern :

1. Object adapter : The `Adapter` class wraps the `Adaptee`.
2. Class adapter : The `Adapter` class inherits from the `Adaptee`.

With this in mind, let us look at the key part of the question being asked :

> Explain whether it would make sense to have B inherit from A and C
>   inherit from B.

It would not make sense to do this for the following reasons :

1. If one is looking to implement the adapter pattern, this cannot be called the *Adapter Pattern* per-se (as `C` is neither an *Object Aadapter* nor a *Class Adapter*)
2. Adapter pattern or not, it violates the *IS-A* relationship. Assume that class `A` is `Android` and class `B` is `Blackberry`. If `B` inherits `A`, it violates the *IS-A* relationship because `Android` is not a `Blackberry`.

Point **2.** above is exactly why we need the *Adapter* pattern. We create a `BlackberryToAndroidAdapter` class that inherits from `Android` and `Blackberry` This is nothing but an example of the *Class Adapter* pattern and in the context of this question, this is the class `C`.